# $.getScript(/mySubFolder/myScript) fails in IE11 in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I am creating an `iframe` in my Web-Application and execute javascript in the `iframe`. It is working with chrome, firefox and edge, but not with ie11.

After my `iframe` has loaded i am using this inside it:

```
 $.getScript("/MySubFolder/bundle.js")
    .done(function () {

    })
    .fail(function (jqxhr, settings, exception) {
      var a = jqxhr; //object with methods
      var b = settings;  //only "error"
      var c = exception; //empty
    });
```

It is within the same domain. The domain is set on my `iframe`. And it is working in all the other browsers.

[image: console out put]

Comment: What's your exception? What's the error?

Comment: only "error" thats the problem

Comment: Check the console. It will give you far more information

Comment: Have you tried using absolute path to script or `"./MySubFolder/bundle.js"`?

Comment: No, because it is working in the other browsers. And I edited the output actually settings says "error" and exception is empty - in the console too

Comment: Added a picture